# Add data frames by index, remove if index not present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two data frames that looks like this:

```
df1 =
                  t   val
2019-08-22 02:00:00   0.1
2019-08-24 02:00:00   0.2
2019-08-26 02:00:00   0.3
2019-08-28 02:00:00   0.4
2019-08-30 02:00:00   0.5

df2 =    
                  t   val
2019-08-24 02:00:00   0.3
2019-08-26 02:00:00   0.4
2019-08-28 02:00:00   0.5
2019-08-30 02:00:00   0.6
```

If they were the same size, I could just do this to add the values with respect to the index `t`:

```
df_sum = df1.set_index('t') + df2.set_index('t')
```

However, in this case `df2` doesn't have as many rows as `df1` so this would fail, and I will get some NaN rows (at least that's what I am getting). So is there any way where it just adds the data frames according to the index, and then just remove the row(s) that doesn't exist in both ? In turn resulting in a data frame with the same number of rows as the one with the smallest number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use merge with default inner join and sum columns:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='t').set_index('t').sum(axis=1).to_frame('val')
print (df)
                     val
t                       
2019-08-24 02:00:00  0.5
2019-08-26 02:00:00  0.7
2019-08-28 02:00:00  0.9
2019-08-30 02:00:00  1.1
```

Or use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and select only rows in both `DataFrame`s by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df11 = df1.set_index('t') 
df22 = df2.set_index('t')
idx = df11.index.intersection(df22.index)

df = df11.loc[idx] + df22.loc[idx]
print (df)
                     val
t                       
2019-08-24 02:00:00  0.5
2019-08-26 02:00:00  0.7
2019-08-28 02:00:00  0.9
2019-08-30 02:00:00  1.1
```

If no misisng values in original data is possible add [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove only added missing values:

```
df = (df1.set_index('t') + df2.set_index('t')).dropna()
print (df)
                     val
t                       
2019-08-24 02:00:00  0.5
2019-08-26 02:00:00  0.7
2019-08-28 02:00:00  0.9
2019-08-30 02:00:00  1.1
```

Comment: The last one actually seems to be working best for my case. Since my code already generates NaN value rows when combining the data frames, this just seems like the easiest one since these rows are the ones that needs to be removed anyways.